# Add JFileChooser to Eclipse Window Builder

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jfilechooser, windowbuilder

I am new to eclipse window builder and want to create a simple GUI with it. I want to add the `JFileChooser`, however it cannot be found in the palette, even though it's a Swing component. I searched through my components, but there is no file chooser.

How can I add the `JFileChooser` to Eclipse Window Builder?

Comment: *"I searched through my components"*  A `JFileChooser` is a window (a top level container, like `JFrame` or `JDialog`) rather than a component (like `JTabbedPane` or `JTable`).  Are you sure you are looking in the right place?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no `JFileChooser` present by default. But you can add it.
Follow the steps:

1. Go to system and click on `Choose Component`

[image]

2.. Now search for your component and add it.

[image]

For further details see this post [JFileChooser and eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743601/jfilechooser-and-eclipse)

Comment: Well structured answer!

Comment: This is excellent advice for any component that's on your class path. I was searching around for this for a while! In my case I wanted to add a JMapViewer map capability to my window and yep, it's just a case of System > Choose Component. It's not as visible as the "Bean" in NetBeans but thank goodness it's still there somewhere.